# random.random vs. numPy.random

Tags: python, numpy, random

I read [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator) the following:

"The Python stdlib module [`random`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random.html#numpy.random.random) contains pseudo-random number generator with a number of methods that are similar to the ones available in `Generator`."

However, the first link for a Python module "random" has a URL that points to Numpy's random.random documentation, not to some general Python library.

Is this link wrong or am I just not getting what the documentation is trying to say here? I'm quite confused by all the different options to generate random numbers in Python. I count at least four now:

1. numPy singleton RandomState object
2. numPy RandomState object
3. numPy Generator object
4. Python's general random functionality apparently.

Any insight is much welcome.

Comment: It's just a markup error that generated a wrong link. The right link is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Comment: You can report the broken link [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues), if you want.

Comment: Use the python `randon` module if you want one number at a time.  Use one of the numpy alternatives to get a whole array of numbers.  `np.random` is easiest to use,  `np.random.default_rng` is newer, but for beginners, not a whole lot different.

Comment: If you include 3rd party libraries like `numpy` in your list of random generators, there are  lots more than 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this link wrong?

Yes. In context, I think they mean [this random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). There are three pieces of evidence for this.

1. It says it's in the stdlib, and NumPy is not in the stdlib. It is an optional library for Python.
2. It's talking about a module, and `np.random.random()` is not a module - it's a function inside a module.
3. Later, in the same paragraph, it says:

   > The Python stdlib module random contains pseudo-random number generator with a number of methods that are similar to the ones available in Generator. It uses Mersenne Twister, and this bit generator can be accessed using MT19937. *Generator, besides being NumPy-aware, has the advantage that it provides a much larger number of probability distributions to choose from.*

   It makes no sense to say that `np.random.random()` is not NumPy-aware - it's part of NumPy. On the other hand, it does make sense to describe the stdlib random module as not being NumPy-aware. The stdlib random module cannot create a NumPy array of random numbers. It's intended to work even if you don't have NumPy installed.